# i have tried to display a button in echo tag for redirection but it dosen't perform any action

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I have used javascript to **redirect** page through button in echo statement but its not working?

```
 echo "<button type='button'onclick='javascript:location ='dalete.php';' class='button'>Delete</button>";
```

Comment: You can confirm whether or not it's running the JS by using `onclick='alert(\"test\")'`. Also, you've spelled "delete" as "dalete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place `javascript:location.href="url"`, example:

```
echo "<button type='button' onclick='javascript:location.href =\"dalete.php\"' class='button'>Delete</button>";
```

Comment: i am using it inside echo so brother this statement will give me error

Comment: Use escape character.

Comment: I am really thanks full to you Anderson it worked at last :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<button type='button' onclick="window.location.href='dalete.php'" class='button'>Delete</button>
```

Comment: ah ok, just saw the edited version of your question. You actually need your button using echo.